# Combining two linux commands

Tags: linux, find, wireshark

Im trying to use mergecap to merge 15 old pcap files in a folder. I tried to use

```
FILES=($(find /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.pcap"  -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lt | tail -15 | awk '{print $8}'))
```

and use mergecap command as `mergecap -w Merge.pcap ${FILES[@]}`  but the mergecap doesnt run when I put it on crontab. Is there any method  to combine these two commands to work properly.

Comment: Does it run from the CLI?

Comment: yes, it works from terminal perfectly.. and I checked all path in the crontab, everything is fine, In syslog it shows that a mail is send just after execution.

Comment: are you running the crontab as root, or as normal user?

Comment: normal user. But I have put the script in sudo crontab -e

Comment: try switching the script to the normal user's crontab. Or, alternatively, leave the script in sudo's crontab, but debug it as sudo. The two options are distinct, you should try both of them.

Comment: You're not quoting `"${FILES[@]}"`?

Comment: @terdon In the mergecap command? no i dint quote

Comment: I've never used mergecap but that might be a possible problem, you should always quote shell variables when expanding, just in case (see suspectus's answer).

Answer (score 0):

try using `printf` to split the array into separate lines:

```
mergecap -w Merge.pcap $(printf -- '%s\n' "${FILES[@]}")
```